# A script in python 2.7 urllib2 and json raises unicode error

Tags: python, json, encoding, urllib2

```
import json
import urllib2
url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=python'
open=urllib2.urlopen(url)
response=open.read().encode('utf8')
data=json.loads(response)
results=data['results']
for result in results:
  print result['from_user'] + ': ' + result['text'] + '\n'
```

gives the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 16-24: character maps to <undefined>`.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking to do is probably to **decode** and not **encode** the response.

A very short explanation why is that the http server doesn't know how to send unicode characters, just byte. Hence it uses an *encoding* like utf-8 to translate these characters into bytes.
When you receive a response from the server you receive this chunk of bytes, and if you want to translate it back into a list of unicode characters (basically a *unicode* object in python) you have to decode them.

What adds more to the confusion is that the lower spectrum of ascii characters (codepoint < 127) are exactly the same as the lower unicode codepoints when using utf-8. A situation where a unicode codepoint is both encoded the same and fits within the range that can be represented in a single byte for each character.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: and I suggested to try using 'decode' instead in my response.